# Delete file with missing inode number

Tags: ext4, lvm

I had some bad sectors on my ext4 partition and using `hdparm --write-sector` I managed to reallocate them. However, I ended up in state where in one folder I have folder that has no inode assigned.

```

```
ls -li /path/

? d?????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? folder
```

```

I am unable to delete this folder now. I tried simply to `rm -fr` it - no success. I wanted to delete it with `debugfs` but opening filesystem that contains this folder gives me *Bad magic number in super-block while opening filesystem*. I don't know whether ext4 in lvm is supported by debugfs and found no info on that.

Comment: have you tried an `fsck` ? (File System Consistency Check), it's very purpose is to help you clean problem like yours. Be sure check you backup first however.

Comment: Well, I wanted to, but that partition is also system partition. If there's no other way, I will try it with some bootable flashdisk.

Comment: Booting with `/forcefsck` will work, even if the partition to check is the system partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest forcing a `fsck`: `sudo touch /forcefsck` and then reboot. But **before you do that**, make sure you have backups — especially now since you can still access the contents of your filesystem.

`debugfs` does support LVM-backed filesystems, it simply uses whatever block device you give it (or even a file). Presumably one of the blocks you reallocated was in the superblock; you could always try to run it using a backup superblock with the `-s` option (which also requires the `-b` option), but it's probably best not to write to the filesystem like that.

Comment: Thanks for advice. As it is company computer, the way I am taking is replacement of the disk. If it was my computer I would do backup and disk check as advised. And therefore, this is accepted answer.